# Trying to populate a nested json file to html

Tags: html, json

I want it to look like this,
How do I detect a link while using the reducer?
While traversing the for loop I want to detect the link and push  tag for the last column

[image: 2]

```js
{
  "alpha": {
    "phone": "11223344",
    "city": "nyc",
    "state": "ny",
    "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=nyc+pictures&oq=nyc+pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.3022j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

  },
  "beta": {
    "phone": "11223344",
    "city": "nyc",
    "state": "ny",
    "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=nyc+pictures&oq=nyc+pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.3022j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
  },
  "gamma": {
    "phone": "11223344",
    "city": "nyc",
    "state": "ny",
    "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=nyc+pictures&oq=nyc+pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.3022j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thank you for adjusting it @mplungjan

Comment: Try with <table><tr><td> to get the output

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce

```js
const data = { "alpha": { "phone": "11223344", "city": "nyc", "state": "ny", "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=nyc+pictures&oq=nyc+pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.3022j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" }, "beta": { "phone": "11223344", "city": "nyc", "state": "ny", "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=nyc+pictures&oq=nyc+pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.3022j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" }, "gamma": { "phone": "11223344", "city": "nyc", "state": "ny", "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=nyc+pictures&oq=nyc+pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.3022j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" } }

document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((acc, ent) => {
    acc.push(`<tr><td>${ent[0]}</td>`);
    Object.entries(ent[1])
      .forEach(([key,val]) => acc.push(
        key === 'link' ? `<td><a href="${val}">Go</a></td>` : `<td>${val}</td>`
      ));
    acc.push(`</tr>`);
    return acc;
  }, []).join('');
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Link</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so so much you are awesome

Comment: Hello sir I have one more ques,

Comment: So when my json has a link,

Comment: I dont want the whole link to be presented on my html, instead i want to convert it to a HYPERLINK,

Comment: See updated code